# Reveal.js lazy loading for php

Tags: javascript, php, reveal.js

When I add this to the last slide in my Reveal.js presentation, it runs right from the start:

```
<section>
   <?php echo "<script>alert('Success!');</script>"; ?>
   The End
</section>
```

How can I make sure that the php runs at the end only?

I was thinking that I could make a separate php file. Then I could use `data-src` to load it. But, I rather not create a separate file. Is there some way that I can run php only at a certain time in the slideshow?

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs at **server-side**, hence it can not be *lazy loaded*.

Also your script is being executed when the DOM is loaded, not when you are on a particular slide.

What you should do is create an event listener for that particular slide/state:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'somestate', function() {
    // TODO: Sprinkle magic
}, false );
```